# Make boxes always the same height with arrows on the same position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How could I make these two boxes to be always the same height, with font awesome arrows always on the same position (bottom right, inside the box)? So the box should stretch depending on the content but the arrows should always be on the same position. Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpprgg?editors=1100

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 30px 50px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia laudantium autem omnis saepe officia alias...</div>
          </h4>
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right float-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia laudantium laudantium autem autem omnis saepe officia alias...
          </h4>
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right float-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `height` of your box `100%` and use `min-height: 200px` instead then use positioning for the icon:

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 30px 50px 30px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.box i {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia laudantium autem omnis saepe officia alias...</div>
          </h4>
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right float-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia laudantium laudantium autem autem omnis saepe officia alias...
          </h4>
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right float-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another posibility is to rely on flex in order to position the icon at the bottom (which I think is better since you are using V4 of bootstrap and all needed classes are ready):

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.box h4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
        <div class="box d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <h4>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia laudantium autem omnis saepe officia alias...</div>
          </h4>
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right align-self-end"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia laudantium laudantium autem autem omnis saepe officia alias...
          </h4>
          <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right align-self-end"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an `arrow` class to your arrow icons like so:

```
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```